# Как заполнить массив структур из двумерного массива

Tags: c

помогите с задачкой. Есть массив.

```
uint8_t macaddr[5][6] = 
{
{0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01}//1
,{0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02}//2
,{0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa}//3
,{0xbb, 0xbb, 0xbb, 0xbb, 0xbb, 0xbb}//4
,{0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc}//5
};
```

и структура:

```
struct alarminfo
{
     uint8_t bssid[6];
     //
     //.....
};
```

создаем массив структур:

```
alarminfo alarm_preset[5];
```

как заполнить массив структур, переменную alarm_preset.bssid[] из массива macaddr 
используя функцию memcpy?

Comment: В цикле. Но если в `struct alarminfo` только одно поле `bssid`, то можно одним `memcpy(alarm_preset, macaddr, sizeof(alarm_preset));`

Comment: `alarminfo alarm_preset[5];`? Что такое `alarminfo`? В приведенном вами коде я вижу только `struct alarminfo`. Никакого просто `alarminfo` я не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct alarminfo *dst = alarm_preset;
for (uint8_t (*src)[6] = macaddr, (*src_end)[6] = src + 5; src != src_end;
       ++src, ++dst)
  memcpy(dst->bssid, src, sizeof *src);
```

или просто

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  memcpy(alarm_preset[i].bssid, macaddr[i], sizeof macaddr[i]);
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось я использовал короткую запись с циклом

Answer (score 0):

Точно также, синтаксис инициализации структур аналогичен массивам:

```
struct alarminfo {
     uint8_t bssid[6];
     //...
};

struct alarminfo alarm_preset[5] = {
      {{0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01}},  //1
      {{0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02}},  //2
      {{0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa}},  //3
      {{0xbb, 0xbb, 0xbb, 0xbb, 0xbb, 0xbb}},  //4
      {{0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc}}   //5
    }
```

Внешние скобки являются инициализатором массива `alarm_preset`, вторые — структур внутри оного, внутренние — массива `bssid` внутри структуры.

ЗЫ: как отмечено, в вопросе пропущен `typedef` или `struct`.